# Send notification when the network route changes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, route, systemd-resolved

I have 2 network interfaces:

- ethernet `enp2s0` with default `metric 1`
- mobile `enx0` with default `metric 2`

When ethernet goes down the metric changes vice versa and I am getting in systems notifications something like this:

```
systemd-resolved[628]: enp2s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
systemd-resolved[628]: enx0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
```

When the ethernet connection is restored it changes back:

```
systemd-resolved[628]: enp2s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
systemd-resolved[628]: enx0: Bus client set default route setting: no
```

I have Ubuntu systemd, and I have self-written script to send any notifications via one of public messengers, so in my case there will be 2 scenario:

1. `send_messenger.sh "me" "the traffic is routed through 4g connection from now, please, be patient"` when ethernet is down and the modem enabled
2. `send_messenger.sh "me" "ethernet is back, the normal bandwidth is available"` when ethernet goes back.

What may be a `systemd` service which may trigger that script when the default route changes? Or one of network interfaces is disconnected?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at, and adapt:a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Comment: Well, it is only about wireless interfaces, isn't it?

Comment: No. Read the script. The meat of it is the `ip monitor address` command. Read `man ip ip-monitor`. One can monitor `link`, `address`, `route`, `mroute`, `prefix`, `neigh`, `netconf`, `rule`, `stats`, `nsid` or `nexthop`. By monitoring `address` I see any address reporting `DOWN`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is that possible to use systemd notify for this purpose?